# Can't merge two free spaces

Tags: 18.04, partitioning

I was trying to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 alone in my laptop (Asus 12Go Ram and 1To storage). I want to customize my partition by my self but when deleting all previous partitions i got two:
/dev/sda free space with 1000204 MB and dev/sdb free space with 128035 MB.
I don't know how to merge them if that is possible. I am not an expert in linux. Can you please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are two physical devices. You can't "merge" them unless you use something like `btrfs`.

Comment: So can I make my swap, root and boot partitions for example to sdb and Home partiton to sda.

Comment: Yes you can, but `/dev/sda` is not a partition. You'll need to create partitions like `/dev/sda1`, etc. But you most likely don't need `root`, `boot` as separate partitions. Modern Ubuntu releases use swap files, not partitions. I suggest installing on one disk a standard way and use the other disk for file storage.

Comment: And are you sure `/dev/sdb` is not the installation media?

Comment: My installation media is just 32Go. I think my laptop has 1To HDD and 128 Go SSD. Thanks, for your suggestions.

Comment: Then install to SSD automatically. Installer will create all you need. You'll be able to change it later.

Comment: May I suggest you open a terminal window and run `sudo parted -l` (that's an l as in lima, not a numeral one)? Please then copy the results, return here, click [edit],, and paste the results into your question so we can see exactly what you've got. Please don't use Add Comment as that would throw away all the formatting and make the result much harder to read. Also, swap partitions are Passé  unless you have added Hibernation to your 18.04; swap files are much easier to manage and don't require a separate swap partition. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq